# Strange behavior on web chatbot but works correctly on python script on terminal

Tags: python, web, ibm-watson

I'm using IBM Watson services to create a web chatbot. The chatbot works perfectly on the terminal but when I use the same python scripts for the web bot some of the answers are displayed correctly but for others the chat restarts as if something crashed and then the welcoming message from the first dialog node of the Watson Assistant appears.

I tried looking on the console of my browser to see if there was an error but no error shows up. How could I proceed to figure out what's going on? Why would it work partially correct on the web and completely fine on the terminal if the code is basically the same thing? I have not even a good idea of what to ask since the error is so puzzling.

Comment: Do you have load balancing on the web part ? What web server are you using? I don't know much about Watson, but thinking about how generally web apps work I'd bet on a "session lost" behavior. I mean I'd expect that the chat with Watson would be a "stateful thing" so you either get sent to an "another server" or the "thread" that was talking to you doesn't recognize you any more ... my 2 cents

Comment: Found the problem. It was a weird one related to the server not finding the instance of a service that was supposed to already have been instantiated so it was re-initiating it over and over... the weird thing is that this only happened with one of the scripts and not the rest. I can't really explain it cause I lack enough knowledge...